# IF statements with psycopg2 and PostGIS in python

Tags: python, postgresql, if-statement, postgis, psycopg2

I am trying to run a SQL query using psycopg2 in python. The query is supposed to create a set of points (in the {nome1} identifier) for each polygon (in the {nome2} identifier, which was created from  the segmentos.json I'm still using to run the for loop) they intersect and save the intersection to a new table (the {nome0} identifier). This bit works fine.

The problem is I want the new {nome0} table to remain droped in case there are no points that intersect the polygon I'm iterating. When I run this code, I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "IF"

Should I be using a function to run IF statements in psycopg2? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

```
intersecta="""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {nome0};
    IF ST_Intersection({nome2}.geom,{nome1}.geom)=true THEN

    SELECT {nome1}.*, {nome2}.nome INTO {nome0}
    FROM {nome2} INNER JOIN {nome1} ON ST_Intersects({nome2}.geom, {nome1}.geom) AND {nome2}.nome=%s;
END IF;
"""
for feature in segmentos.json()['features']:
    nomedosegmento=feature['properties']['nome']
    nomecompleto=str(feature['properties']['nome']+'_'+tabelagerada)

    cur.execute(sql.SQL(intersecta)
                .format(nome0=sql.Identifier(nomecompleto),nome1=sql.Identifier(tabelagerada),nome2=sql.Identifier(segmentnome)),[nomedosegmento,])
    #print(cur.query)


conn.commit()
```

Comment: Why not a regular SQL statement ? `SELECT {nome1}.*, {nome2}.nome ... WHERE ST_Intersection({nome2}.geom,{nome1}.geom)=true`

Comment: but in this case wouldn't it create empty tables if no points fell in the polygon? I'm looking for a way to drop those tables.

Comment: Now i understand :) `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {nome0};` makes it look like you always want to do it, because of the semicolon at the end.

Comment: I actually do always want to do it. I guess I'm UPDATING my tables in a not very elegant way, by using DROP first and then inserting up-to-date values. In any case, I don't want to create empty tables.